# .net Quartz wont run in windows 2003

Tags: quartz.net

i scheduled a quartz scheduler in windows 2003 server. when i am working on 
the system the quartz scheduler is running. 
But when the system is in idle  mode  (i did not touch for some time the system go's to idle) in this case i scheduled a quartz scheduler Every Day at 0 30 1 * * ? * it
doesn't fire  with that expression. is the expression is correct. if
not please let me know the expression. is there any security setting
for quartz scheduler in windows 2003 server and Windows 7.

But every thing works  fine in windows XP

Answer (score 0):

according to [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) your schedule should run every day at 1.30AM.
Where are you hosting your Quartz Scheduler? ASP.NET, Windows Service ?
Are you using a RAMJobStore or a AdoJobStore ?

**UPDATE**:

Few months ago I've developed a custom windows services which hosts Quartz.net.
I've used AdoJobStore to persists my schedules and jobs on a Sql Server database.
The services is running on a Windows 2003 Server 32Bit and I've never experienced any kind of problem so far.

Best thing to do in these situations is to configure your app to do some debugging.
I've explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6570161/219406).

You can download Common.Logging.NLog from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netcommon/files/Common.Logging/).
In the ZIP file you can find all the assemblies you need.
If you're using Quartz.NET 1.0.3 you have to download Common.Logging 1.2.0.

There are more infos about Common Logging infrastructure [here](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: We are hosting it as Windows Service

Comment: @Kirankumar: what about RAMJobStore/AdoJobStore?

Comment: hey sorry ,, we are using  RAMJobStore

Comment: @Kirankumar: I've updated my answer. Try to add some more information to your question, please.

Comment: we are not getting Common.Logging.NLog.., we are getting only Common.Logging.Log4Net. So How can i get that NLog

Comment: @Kirankumar: I've updated my answer with links for the download. Hope it helps.