# Quartz: Why does this Trigger not fire?

Tags: quartz.net

I am using quartz.NET in my project. I have the following problem. I want to run a Scheduled task everyday at 23 o'clock and I am using this code to do that:

```
public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //Download file
    }
}
public interface ISchedule
{
    void Run();
}

public class HelloSchedule : ISchedule
{
    public void Run()
    {

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                                   .WithIdentity("job1")
                                   .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                         .ForJob(job)
                                         .WithIdentity("trigger1")
                                         .StartNow()
                                         .WithCronSchedule("0 0 23 ? * MON-FRI *")
                                         .Build();

        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();
        sc.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        sc.Start();
    }
}
```

but unfortunately it's not firing.
How can I know what the problem is and solve it?
**Thanks for your advice**

Comment: Looks ok. You may need to enable logging and look at the log files. Also, if this is an website, make sure it isn't getting shutdown due to being idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your job will fire at 11pm.
You can check the next fire time for you job using this code:

```
private static DateTime getNextFireTimeForJob(IScheduler scheduler, string jobName, string groupName = "")
    {
        JobKey jobKey = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
        {
            jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, groupName);
        }
        else
        {
            jobKey = new JobKey(jobName);
        }

        DateTime nextFireTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        bool isJobExisting = Scheduler.CheckExists(jobKey);
        if (isJobExisting)
        {
            var detail = scheduler.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
            var triggers = scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);

            var myTrigger = triggers.Where(f => f.Key.Name == "SecondTrigger").SingleOrDefault();


            if (triggers.Count > 0)
            {
                var nextFireTimeUtc = triggers[0].GetNextFireTimeUtc();
                nextFireTime = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(nextFireTimeUtc.Value.DateTime);
            }
        }

        return (nextFireTime);
    }
```

and get the info using this:

```
var nextFireTime = getNextFireTimeForJob(sc, "job1");
```

Make sure your `HelloJob` implements `IJob`.

If you're integrating your Quartz.net scheduler in a WinApp make sure it's created singleton cause it might be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

I test my jobs in a console application and use `Console.ReadLine();` to wait the jobs execution.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Give us more infos about your winApp.

Comment: my application should run everyday at 11pm and do specific task(the task is downloading a file on internet that run in Execute method)

Comment: Consider using some kind of logging system [nLog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6570161/219406).

Comment: Logs would be helpful as your cron expression seems ok and next fire times will be at 11pm as per [this](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: I am getting this error : 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Quartz.ITrigger>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Quartz.ITrigger>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Use [org.Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/package-summary.html) and try this:

```
    JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
    job.setName(Constants.JOB_NAME);
    job.setJobClass(YOUR_JOB_CLASS.class);



    CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
    trigger.setName(Constants.TRIGGER_NAME);
    trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 23 ? * MON-FRI *");

    // schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Your Job class should implement **org.Quartz.Job** interface and override its execute method which does the actual thing the job needs to perform.